# Can someone please explain why I get this error in my ATM python program (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'tuple')

Tags: python, tuples

Ive tested all the code out, but I keep getting this error whenever I try to use the transfer command
Could someone please tell me how to fix it, Im pretty new to all of this.

This is an image of the error
[code-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3CqX.png)

Ive also received this error

Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'tuple'
line 30, in transfer
balance=(bal-amt) + balance
line 58, in 
transfer(balance,amount)

```
name=input("write  your name? ")
balance=float(input("Your current balance? "))

def printMenu():
    print(name,"Welcome to the atm")
    print(""""Pick from the following
          'b'(balance)
          'd'(deposit)
          'w'(withdraw)
          't'(transfer)
          'q'(quit)""")

def getTransaction():
    transaction=str(input("What would you like to do? "))
    return transaction

def withdraw(bal,amt):
    global balance
    balance=bal-amt
    if balance<0:
        balance=balance-10


def formatCurrency(amt):
    return "SR%.2f" %amt


def transfer (bal,amt):
    global balance
    balance=(bal-amt) + balance
    if balance<0:
        print("You dont have enoung funds for that: ")


printMenu()
command=str(getTransaction())

while command!="q":
    if (command=="b"):
        print(name,"Your current balance is",formatCurrency(balance))
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())
    elif (command=="d"):
        amount=float(input("Amount to deposit? "))
        balance=balance+amount
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())
    elif (command=="w"):
        amount=float(input("Amount to withdraw? "))
        withdraw(balance,amount)
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())
    elif (command=="t"):
        Name =print("who would you like to transfer money too")
        print (input("write here: "))
        amount = print, float(input("write here the amount that you will send: "))
        print("You will send {amount}to {Name}")
        transfer(balance,amount)
        command=str(getTransaction())
    else:
        print("Incorrect command. Please try again.")
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())

print(name,"Thank you for using this atm! See you again soon")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
amount = print, float(input("write here the amount that you will send: "))
```

This erroneous line makes `amount` a tuple, hence the error when calling `transfer(balance, amount)`.

No idea what you tried to achieve here, but it should most definitely be changed to

```
amount = float(input("write here the amount that you will send: "))
```